# I don't know how to get an argument to update in a loop in Python3

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, arguments

I want my program to get_time() every time it displays header...

```
def render(header, info, running):
   #scroll header into row 1
   for i in range(0, 16):
      display_text(header, 1, i)
   
   #while running is true scroll through all info strings
   while running == True:
      for i in range(0, 16):
         display_center(header, 1)
         display_text(info, 2, i)
      for i in range(0, 5):
         display_center(header, 1)
         display_center(info, 2)
         sleep(1)
      for i in range(16, 32):
         display_center(header, 1)
         display_text(info, 2, i)

render(get_time(), get_weekday(), True)
```

But it only does get_time() once at the beginning and uses that assignment for the whole function.

I'm pretty new to programming and can't figure this one out....

Comment: You are passing the value returned by `get_time()` into the function. Why not pass it as a function and instead call it every time you need it. `render(get_time, get_weekday(), True)` and then every where you use it `display_center(header(), 1)`

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Is this the "correct way" to do it or am I thinking about it fundamentally wrong?

Comment: There is no problem with passing a function into another function at runtime. However in the event that they share the same scope (Unlikely) we can avoid the assignment altogether and call the function directly. `display_center(get_time(), 1)`